# How can I get an input between two print() functions without going to the next line?

Tags: python

I am trying to build this receipt kind of structure.

[image: This is what I am trying to code]

This is my code:

```
print('--------------------------------')
print('|\tGEOMETRICAL FIGURE\t|')
print('|\t     CALCULATIONS\t|')
print('--------------------------------')
print('|\tFigure:\t\t\t|')
print('|\t1. Circle\t\t|')
print('|\t2. Triangle\t\t|')
print('|\t3. Ellipse\t\t|')
print('|\t4. Trapezium\t\t|')
print('--------------------------------')
print('|\tType number desired\t|')
print('|\t\t',end = '');num = int(input());print('\t\t|')
print('--------------------------------')
```

I am getting this as the output (5 is the user input I gave):

[image: The Output]

How can I get those into one single line?

Comment: As a formatting tip, have a look at [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/).  This will remove the need for the `\t` tabs and give you a lot more control of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. The new line is what the user types, it doesn't come from your program.

To have more fine control over what's on the terminal you need to use curses, that's much more complicated to use, but I think it's the way to go, so you can handle all cases, including errors.

Another way is to turn off the echo in the terminal, so that the typed stuff will not appear on screen. However you'll have to read digit by digit instead of using `input` and display it or the user won't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use one print instead.

```
print(f"|\t\t{int(input())}\t\t|")
```

Comment: But how can I get that value into a variable?

Comment: Ah yeap, you need this value. No ideas then dude. Have a look into a comment below.